# why my a tag dosen't work when I use route("name") to link blade.php files in laravel?

Tags: routes, laravel-blade

I have this in my web.php file.

```
Route::get('contact', function () {
    return view('contact');
})->name('contact');
```

And I have this in my test.blade.php in layouts file.
`<ul><li><a href="{{ route('contact')}}">contact</a></li></ul>`

The contact.blade.php is in views folder.
When I open test.blade.php in the browser and click on the link I get Not Found error.

I checked from the document but I didn't find the problem

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your routes. Run this artisan command

`php artisan route:cache`

or

`php artisan optimize`

This will ensure your new route will be discovered by Laravel.